# Mysql get column value in a single fetch

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I would like to have e single query to get column value without "while"... is possible? I have two table like this...
Owners:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | names | surname |
+------------+---------+
| 1  | John  | Red     |
| 2  | Mark  | Green   |
| 3  | Frank | Yellow  |
| ...| ...   |...      |
+------------+---------+
```

Animals

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id |idOwner | animal |
+-------------+--------+
| 1  | 1      | Cat    |
| 2  | 2      | Bird   |
| 3  | 1      | Dog    |
| ...| ...    |...     |
+-------------+--------+
```

Now I have this code:

```
$query='SELECT * FROM Owners WHERE id=1';
$con=new mysqli($dbhostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
$result=$con->query($query);
$arr=array();
while ($own = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $qry='SELECT animal FROM Animals WHERE idOwner=own["id"]';
    $rslt=$con->query($qry);
    $i=1;
    while ($aml = $rslt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $txt='animal'.$i;
        $own['animal'.$i]=$aml['animal'];
        $i++;
    }
    $arr[]=$own;
}
$con->close();
```

I would like to have the same result but with a single query because now the process is too late... is possible?

Comment: SELECT * FROM owners o 
INNER JOIN animals a ON a.idOwner = o.id 
WHERE o.id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is use a JOIN:

```
SELECT owners.*, animals.animal
FROM owners
LEFT JOIN animals
ON owners.id = animals.idOwner
```

Now you can display all of the owners and their animals in one loop or limit the query to one owner by using a `WHERE` clause. For instance, adding this clause:

```
WHERE owners.id = 1
```

Will return 2 rows from what you're showing in your tables.

---

OP mentions in comments that he desires one row per owner. To get a single row for each owner you will have to employ a sub-query and a `GROUP_CONCAT` (***totally untested***):

```
SELECT owners.*, sub-animals.animal
FROM owners
LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(animal) AS animal
          FROM animals 
          GROUP BY animals.idOwner) AS sub-animals 
ON owners.id = animals.idOwner
```

Comment: thanks... but I would like to have only 1 rows... suggest?

Comment: One row with all of the animals in the row @FrancescoG.? If so, you will need a sub-query for the animals part. Your original question did not state the desired outcome, so maybe this is a different question?

Comment: Yes one row for owner... I would like to have for example... Jhon, Red,..., cat, dog

Comment: Can you setup a SQLFiddle with your data? @FrancescoG.

Comment: SQLFiddle seems to be down at the moment.

Comment: yes... but I have done... thanks so much... There is an error in the query, the correct query is: 
SELECT owners.*, sub-animals.animal
FROM owners
LEFT JOIN (SELECT idOwner, GROUP_CONCAT(animal) AS animal
          FROM animals 
          GROUP BY animals.idOwner) AS sub-animals 
ON owners.id = sub-animals.idOwner

Comment: Excellent! That was why I wanted to test. I am glad that you found the right syntax @FrancescoG.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `JOIN` for one single query as:

```
SELECT o.*,a.animal FROM owners o 
INNER JOIN animals a ON a.idOwner = o.id
```

If you want to add `WHERE id = 1` clause for getting specific user data than you can use this query as:

```
SELECT o.*,a.animal FROM owners o 
INNER JOIN animals a ON a.idOwner = o.id
WHERE o.id = 1
```